# Rendering from loop react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, foreach

I want to iterate over nested object and rendering out for each item an text element in react native.

```
const translationToWeekDays = {
fr_FR: {
  Monday: lundi,
  Tuesday: mardi,
  Wednesday: mercredi,
  Thursday: jeudi,
  Friday: vendredi,
},
};
```

This is the object, and this is my current code

```
          <>
            {Object.values(translationToWeekDays).forEach((week) => {
              Object.values(week).forEach((day) => (
                <Row>
                  <Text>
                    {day}
                  </Text>
                </Row>
              ));
            })}
          </>
```

any directions as to where i am going wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

{Object.values(translationToWeekDays).map((week) =><>
{ Object.values(week).map((day) =>

{day}

)}</>)}

Comment: To clarify, `.forEach` does not have a return value, so that is why `.map` works instead.

Answer (score 0):

Cant make a comment but make sure to use map as it can return jsx...

```
const translationToWeekDays = [
[
  lundi,
  mardi,
  mercredi,
  jeudi,
  vendredi
],
];
```

```
<>
            {translationToWeekDays.map((week) => {
              Object.values(week).map((day) => (
                <Row>
                  <Text>
                    {day}
                  </Text>
                </Row>
              ));
            })}
          </>
```

Comment: Still not rendering out :(

Comment: Oh I misread your post.... you should be using an array not a nested object.. will update code

Comment: what you can do instead if you would like to use the map function is change this to an array and verify the dates by index

Comment: Can't i make it work without chaning the object? I would like to keep the object, there must be a way to render out in a loop with iterating over the nested object

Comment: are there other languages in the parent objcet?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can try this, can be a possible without changing the original object.

```
const translationToWeekDays = {
  fr_FR: {
    Monday: "lundi",
    Tuesday: "mardi",
    Wednesday: "mercredi",
    Thursday: "jeudi",
    Friday: "vendredi"
  }
};

export default function App() 
{

  let daysTranslation = []

  for (let day in translationToWeekDays.fr_FR) 
  {
    daysTranslation.push({
      id: day,
      value: translationToWeekDays.fr_FR[day]
    })
  }


  const daysTranslated = daysTranslation.map(item =>
    {
      return <Text>{item.value}</Text>
    })



  return (
    <Row>
      {daysTranslated}
    </Row>
  );
}
```

However, using Flatlist better than mapping. But this should work for a small list. To loop over content, transforming object into map is the best idea